# Обтекание с выравниванием блоков

Tags: jquery, html, css

Добрый день!
Помогите решить такую задачу: есть неизвестное количество `<div>` с текстом, высота каждого блока разная и заведомо неизвестная. На странице может быть до 100 блоков, они должны обтекать друг друга с выравнивание по высоте. Т.е. получится должно как на сайте pinme.ru (не реклама!!!).

Как сейчас у меня: [ссылка](http://pixs.ru/showimage/Bezimyanni_3514240_11205401.png)
Стили блока:

```
.one_block_info {
    border:1px solid #f2f2f2;
    background:#fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается через jquery плагин masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/